# It's possible to pass an object which has some methods to the child component in the Vue 3 JS

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface, vuejs3

**Parent component** has the method "startMethods" which just also has some other method "onDecrementStart ". OnDecrementStart method just only call Alert.
Under this line, added a code example but that code didn't work.

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="main">
      <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
      <SettingsBoard :max="maxValue" :start="startValue"
               :startInc="startMethods"
      />
     
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SettingsBoard from "@/components/SettingsBoard";

export default {
  name: "Main",
  components: {
    SettingsBoard
  },

  methods: {
    startMethods: {
      onDecrementStart () {
        alert('Decrement')
      },
      onIncrementStart () {
        alert('Incriment')
      }
    },
  }

}
</script>
```

**SettingsBoard component**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
        <label>
          <button :@click="startInc.onDecrementStart()">-</button>
        </label>
      </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "SettingsBoard",
  props: {
    startInc: Object
  },
}
</script>
```

**I want to get like that if it's possible.**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
        <label>
          <button :@click="startInc.onDecrementStart()">-</button>
          <button :@click="startInc.onIncrementtStart()">+</button>
        </label>
      </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "SettingsBoard",
  props: {
    startInc: Object
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a method in the parent component you should emit a custom event which has the parent method as handler :

```
 <label>
      <button @click="$emit('decrement')">-</button>
      <button @click="$emit('increment')">+</button>
    </label>
```

in parent component :

```
<div>
    <SettingsBoard
      @decrement="onDecrementStart"
      @increment="onIncrementStart"
    />


...


 methods: {
    onDecrementStart() {
      this.count--;
    },
    onIncrementStart() {
      this.count++;
    },
  },
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-curie-qwg0y?file=/src/App.vue)**

Comment: Hello, @Boussadjra Brahim. I think so, it's will be work.
But I want to create one object which has two methods.
You just separate one method from the other into "Methods".
But, my idea get like that:
methods: {
 startMethods: {
      onDecrementStart () {
        alert('Decrement')
      },
      onIncrementStart () {
        alert('Incriment')
      }
    },
}

Comment: That syntax is not correct you should put them inside the `methods` object, you're working with vue framework which has its limitations